# why does my regular expression number verification patteren accept dots?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I struggle to understand how i can fix this regular expression patteren.

It verifies normal integer numbers correctly, but when i put a dot in the end of the integer it still verifies as a clean input.

How can i change my patteren /[^0-9]/ so that its only numbers 0-9 that is considered a clean input?

```
        $verify = 1.;
        $regular_exression_filter_integer = "/[^0-9]/";
        if (!preg_match ($regular_exression_filter_integer, $verify)) { 
            echo "clean input";
        } else {
            echo "bad input";
        }

Clean inputs
$filter_this = 1.; 
$filter_this = 1234;

Bad inputs
$filter_this = 1.1;
```

As described the input of $filter_this = 1.;  should give me "BAD INPUT", but it do not.

Comment: remove the ^ from the pattern

Comment: If i remove the ^ it will show "bad input" with integers.

Comment: Please provide sample valid and invalid scenarios with sample strings. Also note that `$verify = 1.;` does not let the code compile since it is not a valid float number. Just have a look, the output for `$verify = "1.";` is ["bad input"](https://ideone.com/LFAMdh).

Comment: @stribizhev Sure, one sec.

Comment: `$verify = 1.` is your issue. That'll amount to just an integer `1` getting assigned.

Comment: (The input to any of the regex functions should be a string,  e.g "1.")

Comment: Some of you are answering a diffferent question, im not going to point fingers, but plese read my question :)

Comment: [echo preg_match ('/^\d+$/', $verify) ? "good" : "bad";](https://eval.in/411648)

Comment: @jonny it still accepts the ending dot eg 1.

Comment: `$verify = 1.; var_dump($verify);` > `float(1)` > [good](https://eval.in/411660) `$verify = "1."; var_dump($verify);` > `string(2) "1."` > [bad](https://eval.in/411660)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot run a regex check on integers of floats, only on strings.

Also, you can make use of a positive `preg_match` with a regex that checks for integer value in the input that ends in an optional dot:

```
$regular_expression_filter_integer = '/^[0-9]+\.?$/';
$verify = "1.";
if (preg_match ($regular_expression_filter_integer, $verify)) { 
    echo "clean input";
} else {
    echo "bad input";
}
```

See [demo](https://ideone.com/VlyQHR)

Comment: That is a really good example, so far i am as well. But what if i want to get a false response to integer with an ending dot?

Comment: Just remove the `\.?` from the regex pattern, and [it will be disallowed](https://regex101.com/r/yA6oY3/1) (preg_match will return `false`).

Comment: I got it to work now with your example. Thanks for your paitience, and your help :-)

Answer (score -2):

You could try this perhaps.

```
    $verify = 1;
    $pttn = "@^[\d{1}]$@";
    $res=preg_match ( $pttn, $verify, $matches );
    echo $res ? 'clean input' : 'bad input';
```

Comment: 1.1 verifies as a clean input, how can that be treated as bad input? :)